# Creating and options using data from php and submitting to request for data using the options HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html

I am very new to HTML and PHP. I have a database in phpadmin I used the data from the table as an option for the droplist in HTML. Now that I can view the options, I'm stuck on the button as I have no idea how to use the selected option to request for data from another table.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
<head>

<title> Unitited document </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content ="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>


<body>
<form name="form1" action="fortest2.php" method="post">
<select> <?php $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','carpark_project'); 
$result = $conn->query("select development from carpark_availability");

while($row =$result->fetch_assoc())
{ ?>
    <option><?php echo $row["development"]; ?> </option> <?php

} ?>
echo "<input type=submit value = Update>

</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `echo "<input type=submit value = Update>` to `<input type="submit"  value="Update" />`. You have a Syntax error in the `input` tag and you are specifying the Php `echo` command outside of the Php start/end markers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the selected value from the dropdown you can fire a change event. This change event will have a ajax call, which will fetch the required data from the server and pass it to the client browser.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ActionUrl,
            data: {selectedValue: value },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }, error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('XMLHttpRequest:' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                console.log('textStatus:' + textStatus);
                console.log('errorThrown:' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```